# How to transition to the main application flow after initial onboarding

Tags: ios

Currently I have two flows laid in storyboard: the onboarding / login flow (currently set as the initial view controller in storyboard settings) and the main application flow (e.g. the core application experience after you're logged in).

The transition from onboarding to the main app flow happens successfully in the UI, but I don't think the way I'm doing it is quite right. One problem I'm having is the inability to restore view state to the main application flow.

When transitioning from the onboarding flow to the main app flow, I'm using `presentViewController` to transition to the new view controller, and then I'm removing the presenting view controller's parent navigation controller from it's view hierarchy using `removeFromParentViewController`. My idea here is that the main app flow should really have it's own view hierarchy, the root of which should be the first view in the newly presented view controller.

However, doing things in this manner breaks the view restoration code. It seems I'm somehow failing to properly "reset" the view hierarchy to the main navigation controller. View state restoration was working before when I was not removing the onboarding navigation controller from the view hierarchy (as in the code below), but now it's not working -- state is always restored back to the beginning of the onboarding flow, the `- (void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder` method is never called on the main app flow controller.

Below is the relevant code from the onboarding flow controller that presents the main app flow controller.

```objective-c
// The presenting view controller from the onboarding flow
@implementation TLOnboardingStep2ViewController
  -(void)presentMainViewController {
      UIStoryboard *board = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

      // The root view controller of the main app flow
      ECSlidingViewController *slidingVC = [board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"slidingViewController"];
      [self presentViewController:slidingVC animated:YES completion:^{
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window].rootViewController = slidingVC;
          [self.navigationController removeFromParentViewController];
      }];
  }
@end
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a better way to handle this is to make the main application flow the root view controller, and pop into the login flow as a modal view controller from the main view controller when needed. This is what I'm doing now and it seems to be working a lot better, and keeping the hierarchy much cleaner.

Comment: Yes, this is a better approach. You can set animated to NO when you present the login modal so that you don't initially see the root view controller until after you've successfully logged in. Then you can dismiss it with animated set to YES.

Comment: @Jesse A example with some code would be very useful - thanks